# # Symbol preventing data from going from one form page to another Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c

In an Oracle Apex 4.2 form when a user has entered a '#' symbol into the text field it's preventing the data from the other fields to carry over when your using the "Set These Items With These Values" function.

The application is a staffing management app, the recruiters will click on a "Submit to Req" button that will pop open another window in a modal (skillbuilders modal plugin was used) asking if they're sure they want to submit and will also show a list of previously submitted candidates that's generated from the req number that's placed in a hidden field in the submittal.

Now, on this page there are also hidden fields that pull information from the job requirements table so when the recruiter clicks on the "Yes" button, it populates the client name, job name, sales name, req number and req priority fields in the candidate submittal form so we're able to track this information better for management.

Often times the sales staff will put the client's job number in with the # symbol, ex: Job #123456, into the job field.

When someone does that, it's preventing the next field that is a hidden field from being carried over and populating that field.

I had a similar issue previously with commas, and using a / in the "Set These Items With These Values" are I was able to work around that problem, but that isn't working for the # symbol.

As of right now I've asked sales to not use that symbol, but that's not a long term answer here.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: When you examine the Ajax post request in your browser, what do you see? Are the values being transferred correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve this issue is to use the Whitelist option available.
Steps are as follows:

1. Edit the Textfield item
2. Click on Security tab or scroll to Security section in the edit page.
3. From the Restricted Characters dropdown select Whitelist for a-Z, 0-9 and space.
4. Click Apply Changes.

When user enters the `#` character and tries to proceed, APEX will throw an error message as

`Job field contains special characters. Only the characters a-Z, 0-9 and spaces are allowed.`

This way user is restricted to use only the whitelisted characters.